ERC20 Token owner can transfer token from any wallet address?
ERC20 Token owner can transfer token from any wallet address ?

If a ERC20 token owner can transfer tokens from any wallet address to other wallet address ?
The contract have transfer token function
Code :
function transferFrom(
address sender,
address recipient,
uint256 amount
) external returns (bool);
If possible ? How to prevent ?

If a ERC20 token owner can transfer tokens from any Contract address to other address ?
if the token holder is a contract(owned by someone not with token owner control means ( Token owner can transfer )


I tried in test net , Its showing huge fees
